# iTextSharp change font of all text in column

Tags: css, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating a PDF that takes a string of html then uses HTMLWorker.ParseToList and adds each element to a column. No matter what I try I can't change the font.

I was trying to add the font to each element as I add it: 
el.Font = times;
But that throws an error.

Below is my current code. I want all text to appear in Times Roman.

```
var specialConditionsText = "<p>Special Conditions</p><p>A. More</p><p>B. Section B</p><p>C. Section C</p><ul><li>Bullet 1</li><li>Bullet 2</li></ul><ol><li>Number list 1</li><li>Number List 2<ol><li>Number list sub</li></ol></li></ol><p><br></p>";
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.UL, HtmlTags.INDENT, "14");
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.OL, HtmlTags.INDENT, "14");
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.LI, HtmlTags.LEADING, "18");

BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.NORMAL);

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(specialConditionsText))
{
//Get our raw PdfContentByte object letting us draw "above" existing content
PdfContentByte cb = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(11);

//Create a new ColumnText object bound to the above PdfContentByte object
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

//Create a single column object spanning the entire page
ct.SetSimpleColumn(60, 190, 570, 720);

//Convert our HTML to iTextSharp elements
List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, styles);

//Loop through each element
foreach (IElement el in elements)
{
      //Add the element to the ColumnText
      el.Font = times;
      ct.AddElement(el);
}

ct.Go();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont` instead of `BaseFont.CreateFont`?

Comment: I just added this: Font times = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);
which loads the font, but I'm still not sure how to apply that font to the text.

Comment: Just FYI, if you are using `HTMLWorker`, it means that you are using a version of iTextSharp that is at least 7 years old. In current versions you would use `XMLWorker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found was:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();

styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "times new roman");
styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
```

The final code I used looked like this. Hope it helps someone.

```
specialConditionsText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(specialConditionsText);
                        specialConditionsText = specialConditionsText.Replace("<br>", "<br />");
                        specialConditionsText = specialConditionsText.Replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "<br />");

                        FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();

                        StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
                        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.UL, HtmlTags.INDENT, "14");
                        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.OL, HtmlTags.INDENT, "14");
                        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.LEADING, "13");
                        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "11");
                        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "times new roman");
                        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");

                        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(specialConditionsText))
                        {
                            //Get our raw PdfContentByte object letting us draw "above" existing content
                            PdfContentByte cb = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(11);

                            //Create a new ColumnText object bound to the above PdfContentByte object
                            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

                            //Create a single column object spanning the entire page
                            ct.SetSimpleColumn(85, 192, 530, 720);

                            //Convert our HTML to iTextSharp elements
                            List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, styles);

                            //Loop through each element
                            foreach (IElement el in elements)
                            {
                                //Add the element to the ColumnText
                                ct.AddElement(el);
                            }

                            ct.Go();
                        }
```

Comment: Not sure but it looks like this would apply same font for the whole document. You can use Phrase, Chunks to customize the font appearance for even the tiniest text block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to add the text with required font. This uses addtext function instead of addelement and then uses phrase (even chunk can be used).

```
ct.AddText(new Phrase(el.ToString(), times));
```

You can use either of the methods (FontFactory.GetFont, BaseFont.CreateFont) for creating the required font style.

Check the below link for more details on formatting with itextsharp:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/89/itextsharp-page-layout-with-columns